# Google Maps V3 : MarkerClusterer is not collapsing to markers ?? (VERY STRANGE)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a lot of  markers on my map, so i implemented marker Clusterer !
But, Strangly..

MarkerClusterer collapses to smaller values 244 > 32 > 4 > 2
But after I click 2 -> I should be able to see both the markers, but its collapsing the last 2.

Everything was working fine untill I made the markers to load via ajax !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default minimum cluster size for the markerCLusterer is 2. So you should set it to 1 when calling for a new MarkerClusterer;

```
var CLUSTER_MINIMUM_SIZE = 1;
markerCluster = MarkerClusterer(map, [], { minimumClusterSize: CLUSTER_MINIMUM_SIZE }))
```

You can find brief explanation for the optional constructor parameters inside the javascript file of the markerclusterer.

Comment: No...
This doesn't helped.. at all..
Still facing the same problem !!

Comment: Solved the problem.. actually I was adding the same marker twice !

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, one marker with a label of "2" that would not collapse all the way, I double checked and the marker was NOT being added twice.

I was able to get the desired behavior by increasing the minimumClusterSize to 3. That is the only way I could find to solve the problem, hope it helps someone.